# Trying to create an ElementaryOS PV guest on Xen

Tags: xen, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to install ElementaryOS as a pv guest on my server for testing purposes.

Elementary OS is a fork of Ubuntu Precise. Elementary does not come with PV support, however, I can obtain the corresponding ubuntu images from:

> [mirror]/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/xen/initrd.gz
>   [mirror]/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/xen/vmlinuz

Here is a copy of my elementaryOS.cfg

```
name = "elementary"
kernel = "/home/curios/elementary/vmlinuz"
ramdisk = "/home/curios/elementary/initrd.gz"
memory = "1024"
disk = [ "phy:/dev/vg0/elementary,sda1,w", "file:/home/curios/elementary/elementaryos-stable-amd64.20130810.iso,sdb,r" ]
vif = ['bridge=xenbr0']
on_reboot = 'destroy'
on_poweroff = 'destroy'
```

So far it's working but I just got the following error which I am concerned about. Would somebody look over my cfg and make sure I have everything set up correctly?

```
  ┌────────────────────────┤ [!!] Partition disks ├─────────────────────────┐
  │                                                                         │
  │ Error informing the kernel about modifications to partition             │
  │ /dev/xvda1p1 -- Invalid argument.  This means Linux won't know about    │
  │ any changes you made to /dev/xvda1p1 until you reboot -- so you         │
  │ shouldn't mount it or use it in any way before rebooting.               │
  │                                                                         │
  │ ERROR!!!                                                                │
  │                                                                         │
  │                                Ignore                                   │
  │                                Cancel                                   │
  │                                                                         │
  │     <Go Back>                                                           │
  │                                                                         │
  └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Of course, I could just install elementaryOS as an HVM guest, but this is more challenging.

Thank you for your help and advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Original post**: Xen project Mailing List http://goo.gl/nDsyo5

```
Looks like you're mapping the LV as xvda1. Don't do that if you're
using OS installer. Map it as xvda instead.

You should only map block devices as (xv/s/h)da1 if you're using tools
like debootstrap/yum or doing manual copy from an existing system.

Also if you want to use ext4 as "/", don't forget to have a separate
/boot with ext3 since like Mark said, by default Centos' pygrub
doesn't support ext4.

-- 
Fajar
```

In my case, i've changed in filename.cfg xvda1 to xvda (see example):

```
disk        = [
                  'phy:/dev/vgxen/calculus-root,xvda,w'
              ]
```

Comment: Thank you, it's been sometime since I've thought about this problem but I believe I solved it just as you described - by mapping it to xvda.